# Single Mailbox with multiple addresses - how to create rule to sort into folder?

Tags: exchange, rules, exchange-2013

I have been tasked to try an alternative approach to mail-enabled public folders that are in use in our organization.

I have created a shared mailbox that is targeted to collect emails sent to several addresses with future plans to assign those addresses directly to that mailbox if it would work. I did that with a server-side rule of kind "If a message is sent to (list of public folders), BCC to (shared mailbox)". Then, I have used Outlook Web Access to create nested folders in that mailbox and create several rules that I intended to work server side to sort e-mails based on recipient address. These, however, do not work. The rules are all of this type of rule: "If the message contains "a@contoso.com" as recipient, move to folder "a" and stop processing other rules". This way I intended to make Exchange sort messages into those public folders for me. This didn't work, no rules get triggered, and all email that's redirected to the shared mailbox, remains in inbox root.

How should I formulate mailbox rules to sort mail based on recipients  address? Is it even possible? If not, then this idea is not viable.

Comment: I wonder if you have a proper understanding of SMTP.   You might want to reword this message focusing on what you are trying to achieve - there is, to the best of my knowledge, no such thing as an SMTP address - SMTP stands for "Simple Mail Transfer *Protocol*".   The SMTP protocol itself has no knowledge of mail folders - this is all handled by the mail user agent - ie outlook (or sometimes by plugins like procmail or spamassassin)

Comment: @davidgo I mean that a mailbox has several SMTP addresses assigned, then a sender from *elsewhere* where no internal data such as address books is available sends a message to one of them. The message ends in the mailbox, and NOW I want a rule to trigger and move that message to an appropriate folder.

Comment: Again, there is no such thing as an SMTP address.   I strongly suspect you are simply meaning "recipient address", and the the questions you are asking relate to Outlooks ability to filter on recipient address.   If this is the case, throwing the word SMTP all over your post attracts the wrong viewers - people who specialize in SMTP services (like myself) are not well correlated with people who specialize in Outlook rule writing (which really has nothing to do with SMTP)

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure Outlook (or in case of shared mailboxes, OWA and Exchange mailbox rule engine) does not have access to SMTP-related data of received message? Maybe I'm wrongly spelling "SMTP address" meaning message recipient address within SMTP data exchange session (`RCPT TO: a@contoso.com` part). You can edit the question if you can reword it to use correct terminology for entities involved.

Comment: By the way, Exchange designates these addresses as "email addresses of type SMTP", this is naturally shortened to "SMTP address". I actually expect this to be somewhat common name for e-mail addresses of type `user@domain.com`.